# What's the meaning of the ocaml code for Redefinition and combination in partial functions

Tags: function, ocaml, first-order-logic, formal-methods

I am reading the book of *Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning*. It has some code to define finite partial functions in the file  `lib.ml`. I could not understand the meaning of the code of redefinition and combination in partial functions.  What is the purpose of the `newbranch` subfunction? The code is as following:

```
type ('a,'b)func =
    Empty
  | Leaf of int * ('a*'b)list
  | Branch of int * int * ('a,'b)func * ('a,'b)func;;

(* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(* Redefinition and combination.                                             *)
(* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

let (|->),combine =
  let newbranch p1 t1 p2 t2 =
    let zp = p1 lxor p2 in
    let b = zp land (-zp) in
    let p = p1 land (b - 1) in
    if p1 land b = 0 then Branch(p,b,t1,t2)
    else Branch(p,b,t2,t1) in
  let rec define_list (x,y as xy) l =
    match l with
      (a,b as ab)::t ->
      let c = Pervasives.compare x a in
      if c = 0 then xy::t
      else if c < 0 then xy::l
      else ab::(define_list xy t)
    | [] -> [xy]
  and combine_list op z l1 l2 =
    match (l1,l2) with
      [],_ -> l2
    | _,[] -> l1
    | ((x1,y1 as xy1)::t1,(x2,y2 as xy2)::t2) ->
      let c = Pervasives.compare x1 x2 in
      if c < 0 then xy1::(combine_list op z t1 l2)
      else if c > 0 then xy2::(combine_list op z l1 t2) else
        let y = op y1 y2 and l = combine_list op z t1 t2 in
        if z(y) then l else (x1,y)::l in
  let (|->) x y =
    let k = Hashtbl.hash x in
    let rec upd t =
      match t with
        Empty -> Leaf (k,[x,y])
      | Leaf(h,l) ->
        if h = k then Leaf(h,define_list (x,y) l)
        else newbranch h t k (Leaf(k,[x,y]))
      | Branch(p,b,l,r) ->
        if k land (b - 1) <> p then newbranch p t k (Leaf(k,[x,y]))
        else if k land b = 0 then Branch(p,b,upd l,r)
        else Branch(p,b,l,upd r) in
    upd in
  let rec combine op z t1 t2 =
    match (t1,t2) with
      Empty,_ -> t2
    | _,Empty -> t1
    | Leaf(h1,l1),Leaf(h2,l2) ->
      if h1 = h2 then
        let l = combine_list op z l1 l2 in
        if l = [] then Empty else Leaf(h1,l)
      else newbranch h1 t1 h2 t2
    | (Leaf(k,lis) as lf),(Branch(p,b,l,r) as br) ->
      if k land (b - 1) = p then
        if k land b = 0 then
          (match combine op z lf l with
             Empty -> r | l' -> Branch(p,b,l',r))
        else
          (match combine op z lf r with
             Empty -> l | r' -> Branch(p,b,l,r'))
      else
        newbranch k lf p br
    | (Branch(p,b,l,r) as br),(Leaf(k,lis) as lf) ->
      if k land (b - 1) = p then
        if k land b = 0 then
          (match combine op z l lf with
             Empty -> r | l' -> Branch(p,b,l',r))
        else
          (match combine op z r lf with
             Empty -> l | r' -> Branch(p,b,l,r'))
      else
        newbranch p br k lf
    | Branch(p1,b1,l1,r1),Branch(p2,b2,l2,r2) ->
      if b1 < b2 then
        if p2 land (b1 - 1) <> p1 then newbranch p1 t1 p2 t2
        else if p2 land b1 = 0 then
          (match combine op z l1 t2 with
             Empty -> r1 | l -> Branch(p1,b1,l,r1))
        else
          (match combine op z r1 t2 with
             Empty -> l1 | r -> Branch(p1,b1,l1,r))
      else if b2 < b1 then
        if p1 land (b2 - 1) <> p2 then newbranch p1 t1 p2 t2
        else if p1 land b2 = 0 then
          (match combine op z t1 l2 with
             Empty -> r2 | l -> Branch(p2,b2,l,r2))
        else
          (match combine op z t1 r2 with
             Empty -> l2 | r -> Branch(p2,b2,l2,r))
      else if p1 = p2 then
        (match (combine op z l1 l2,combine op z r1 r2) with
           (Empty,r) -> r | (l,Empty) -> l | (l,r) -> Branch(p1,b1,l,r))
      else
        newbranch p1 t1 p2 t2 in
  (|->),combine;;
```

Could you please explain the meaning of this code for me?

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? What in particular you cannot understand?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I do not understand the meaning of the subfunction "newbranch".

Answer (score 6):

Those trees are called Patricia trees and they're a form of [Radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).
John Harrison uses them as finite partial functions, i. e. immutable hash trees that are unique representations of partial functions.

To understand the functions you have to understand the trees.

### Explanation of the trees

```ml
| Leaf of int * ('a*'b)list
```

The int argument in the leaves is a hash value of the key.
The list after the hash value is a sorted associative list of key-value pairs where all the keys have the same hash value. Little-endian prefixes of these hash values will be stored in the branches.

If `k = 00111001` in binary big-endian notation, then `1001` is a big-endian suffix or little-endian prefix of `k`. Since all ints have a fixed number of bits, the prefixes are extended with zeors. The prefix becomes something like `00001001` in the program.

```ml
| Branch of int * int * ('a,'b)func * ('a,'b)func
```

You should think of these ints as little-endian bit arrays, not as ints. The first int is the common little-endian prefix for the two sub-trees. The second int marks the position of the first bit that differs. These two ints are used as bit-masks. In `Branch (p, b, t1, t2)` the tree `t1` has a prefix that extends `p` with a `0` at the position `b`. The tree `t2` also has a prefix that extends `p` but with `1` at the position `b`.

### Here are some rules to understand the code:

- Whenever you see a `t`, `t1` or `t2` then it's a Patricia tree. (type `('a, 'b) func`)
- The variables `p`, `p1` or `p2` denote binary little-endian prefixes (= big-endian suffixes) of hash values. (type `int`)
- The variables `b`, `b1`, `b2` and so on mark the first bit that differs. (type `int`) There's only one bit `1`, the others are `0` if I remember correctly.
- The variable `c` is the result of a comparison, i.e. only `=0`, `>0` or `<0` matters, not the actual value. (type `int`)
- The variable `k` is a hash value of a key. (type `int`)

### Explanation of the function `newbranch`

```ml
let newbranch p1 t1 p2 t2 =
```

We want to combine two trees `t1` and `t2` with prefixes `p1` and `p2` respectively. The assumption is that the two prefixes differ.

```ml
let zp = p1 lxor p2 in
let b = zp land (-zp) in
```

This is bit-fiddling to get the first bit in `p1` and `p2` that actually differs. It uses the fact that the arithmetic negative on integer numbers is implemented using two's complement and increment.
In big-endian binary notation:
If `p1 = 00111001` and `p2 = 00011001` then `b = 00100000`.

```ml
let p = p1 land (b - 1) in
```

Now that `b` only contains one bit, `b - 1` has ones until that bit position, e.g. if `b = 00100000` in binary then `b-1 = 00011111`. So `b-1` can be used as a bit-mask to get the common little-endian prefix (= big-endian suffix) of `p1` and `p2` out of `p1`. Note that you could also use `p2` here since it's the common prefix.

Now that we have calculated the common prefix and the bit position, the only thing that is needed to compute the new `Branch` is the order of the two sub-trees:

```ml
if p1 land b = 0 then Branch(p,b,t1,t2)
else Branch(p,b,t2,t1)
```

If `p1` has a `0` at the bit position `b` then it comes first.

Keeping this explanation in mind it'll be easy to understand the rest of the code. Test cases and printing some values of the variables will help you a lot.

The function `combine` is a bit more involved because care is taken not to leave any branches empty! The trees should be *unique representations* of finite partial functions. The expression `t1 = t2` on patricia trees will return `true` if and only if `t1` and `t2` represent the same function. This explains the great number of constructs like `match .. with Empty -> ..`.

### Explanation of the function `define_list`

The function `define_list` inserts a key-value pair `(x, y)` into the sorted list `l` that has no duplicate keys.
If the key `x` is already in the list then its value is replaced.
Of course `l` is not modified but a new modified list is returned. This is functional programming after all.
The list `l` is sorted according to the keys and `Pervasives.compare` is used
to compare the keys.

```ml
match l with
  (a,b as ab)::t ->
    let c = Pervasives.compare x a in
    if c = 0 then xy::t
```

If `(a, b)` is the head of `l` and
`x = a` (which is the same thing as `c = 0`) then `(x, y)` replaces `(a, b)`.
(Since `a` and `x` are equal in this case you could use `(a, y)` to replace `(a, b)` but then you would have constructed a new pair. The name `xy` is used explicitly to avoid the construction of a new pair for performance reasons.)

```ml
  else if c < 0 then xy::l
  else ab::(define_list xy t)
```

Otherwise, the pair `(x, y)` is inserted before or after `(a, b)` depending on whether
`x` is smaller than `a`, i.e. `c < 0`, or greater than `a`, i.e. `c > 0`.

John Harrison could have used the expressions `x = a` instead of `c = 0`
and `x < a` instead of `c < 0` but then he would have used two comparisons implicitly calling `Pervasives.compare` instead of just one.
The function `Pervasives.compare` can be slow because it recursively descends into
arbitrary values. The expression `c > 0` is just a comparison of ints so it's fast.

The function `define_list` is only used during hash collisions.

### Explanation of the function `|->`

The function `|->` does almost the same thing as `define_list` but for trees instead of lists. You could call it `define_tree` or `define_finite_partial_function`. I guess if OCaml had Unicode identifiers, John Harrison would have used the maplet arrow: ↦ (\mapsto in LaTeX). The expression `(x |-> y) t` builds a finite partial function that is like `t` except that the key `x` now maps to the value `y`.

```ml
let (|->) x y =
  let k = Hashtbl.hash x in
  let rec upd t =
```

The definition descends into the tree but there's no need to recompute the hash value `k` of `x` over and over again. It is computed first and after that the recursion takes place inside the local function `upd` which delegates most of its work.

The first two cases of the pattern-matching are almost self-explaining:

```ml
match t with
    Empty -> Leaf (k,[x,y])
  | Leaf(h,l) ->
    if h = k then Leaf(h,define_list (x,y) l)
    else newbranch h t k (Leaf(k,[x,y]))
```

- If there's no content, just create a leaf. Remember that `[x,y]` is the same thing as `[(x, y)]`. It's just bad style to omit the parenthesis. (A list with two elements would be `[x; y]`.)
- If there's a leaf with the same hash value (hash collision), the key-value pair `(x, y)` goes into the list of this leaf. This is the job of `define_list`.
- If the hash value doesn't match, find a common prefix of the hash values and create a new branch. This is the job of `newbranch`. (`[x,y]` is `[(x, y)]`)

For the last case you have to remember how to read the bit-fiddling:

```ml
| Branch(p,b,l,r) ->
    if k land (b - 1) <> p then newbranch p t k (Leaf(k,[x,y]))
    else if k land b = 0 then Branch(p,b,upd l,r)
    else Branch(p,b,l,upd r)
```

- If `k` doesn't match the prefix `p`, then find a new common prefix and create a new branch. (`[x,y]` is `[(x, y)]`)
- If `k` matches the prefix `p` and the next bit is `0`, then descend into the left sub-tree.
- If `k` matches the prefix `p` and the next bit is `1`, then descend into the right sub-tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helpful. Could you please explain the meaning of the functions 'define_list' and '|->' briefly? Thank you very much!

Comment: @WuZhu I've added an explanation of `define_list`. I'll write about `|->` when time permits.

Comment: @WuZhu Do not forget to accept the answer, if it solves your problem.